# Copy file from one dropbox account to other dropbox account in C# using dropbox api

Tags: c#, .net, dropbox-api, spring-social

I have two users say **Bob** and **Alice** already authorized with my application **MyApp**. It is possible for me to download the file from Bob to my server and upload the file to Alice. Is there any way to directly send the file from Bob to Alice without the need for downloading and uploading the file at server and without folder sharing? The result is that the same file should appear with both user's folder and these should exist as two different entities. I am using SpringSocial .net package for dropbox services.

Comment: Have a shared a folder between both?

Comment: A lot of files would be there and a file may be shared with many others, so folder sharing is not an option in my case

Comment: you can share a folder with many of them but I dont want to comment more because I dont know what is `spring-social`.

Comment: @Mr_Green I do know that, but I dont want folder sharing, read my edit

Comment: The only way this is possible is upload the file to both accounts since you don't want to share the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality is provided by the "copy reference" feature of the Dropbox API:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/16

Documentation:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#copy_ref
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/api#fileops-copy